# Is it possible to scrape a website with a login using purely javascript - on client side

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I've managed to scrape websites that require no login using js only and a little help from websites that allow me to pass the CORS issues(like allorigins), but I just couldn't manage to get pass through the login problem.
I've seen many posts discussing of doing it using node.js and python beautifulsoup, but none on how to do it with javascript.

So how do I go about it?
Is it even possible doing it purely on client-side?

I'm willing to do all the learning and searching needed, but I need some direction in this vast subject.

Comment: Unless you find a 3rd party site that supports doing this, you can't.

Comment: Define scrap a website?

Comment: @MadeInDreams extract data from a website

Comment: The word is "scrape," with an "e." "Scrap" means something else entirely.

Comment: Could you please provide specific example and code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant using in-browser JavaScript, how did you get around [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)? And if you did, then once the page refreshed after a successful login you code would stop running anyway unless you were a browser extension.

If you mean on your computer, then Node *is* what you're looking for, but unless you use a project like [Headless Chrome](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) then you'll run into the issue of saving the cookies between requests which is what keeps track of your session and actually keeps you logged in.

Comment: I got around it using sites like this http://multiverso.me/AllOrigins/. thank you for the answer

Comment: @naor.z If that solved your issue, could you please post the solution as an answer and accept it?

Comment: @omegastripes while this answer is helpful it doesn't answer the original question. I upvoted but it's not the answer I seeked..

Answer (score 1):

Login requires a direct interaction with your browser, like saving a cookie, returning a security token etc.

If you use JavaScript from a html page, it would theoretically require to visit the other page, at least inside a iFrame. There is a limit of how much you can do with javascript inside a iFrame.

With other words you try to imitate something like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). Give it a try. It works with Java. You can control you browser, telling what to do, like a real user, and fetch the results, make even screenshots.